# Cfgrib is not installed correctly on WSL2 through pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.8, cfgrib

I'm trying to install `cfgrib` to my WSL2 Ubuntu however when I type `python3 -m cfgrib selfcheck` it gives the following error as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/berke/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cfgrib/messages.py", line 42, in <module>
    import pyeccodes.compat as eccodes
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyeccodes'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 143, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 110, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/home/berke/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cfgrib/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .cfmessage import CfMessage
  File "/home/berke/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cfgrib/cfmessage.py", line 29, in <module>
    from . import messages
  File "/home/berke/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cfgrib/messages.py", line 44, in <module>
    raise exc
  File "/home/berke/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cfgrib/messages.py", line 37, in <module>
    from . import bindings as eccodes
  File "/home/berke/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cfgrib/bindings.py", line 57, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(f"ecCodes library not found using {LIBNAMES}")
RuntimeError: ecCodes library not found using ['eccodes', 'libeccodes.so', 'libeccodes']
```

My python version is `Python 3.8.2`. Is it possible to install cfgrib through `pip`?

Answer (score 1):

The latest release of `cfgrib` version 0.9.8.5 at PyPI [doesn't declare `eccodes` or `pyeccodes` as a dependency](https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib/blob/c54f08ce969fbaca53596085b9022c8ee398e4c1/setup.py#L52), not even as extra. You can install one of them separately:

```
pip install eccodes
```

or

```
pip install pyeccodes
```

(I don't know what is the difference; `cfgrib` can [use both](https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib/blob/c54f08ce969fbaca53596085b9022c8ee398e4c1/cfgrib/messages.py#L32)).

The bug [is fixed in the repository](https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib/blob/72ee9dfd8715d6cf6e4c01dc35ecc94852868340/setup.py#L50) but not yet released to PyPI so you can try to install the latest version using `git`:

```
pip install --upgrade "git+https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib.git#egg=cfgrib"
```

Comment: also beneficial ```https://github.com/ecmwf/eccodes-python/issues/16```